# Find the Children of a Page then Echo it as a Bulleted List of Links (menu)

Tags: theme-development, menus, sub-menu

I am trying to check if a parent Page has children. If it has children I would like to echo the children as a bulleted list with links to each child (basically a menu).

Right now I have the following code in loop-page.php and it checks if the Page has any children and returns an array with the children. I use an if statement to check if the number is greater than 0.

```
$children = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID.'&parent='.$post->ID);

if (count($children)) {
    // Echo children as a bulleted list of links
}
```

This part seems to work.

My question is how do I echo through the children as a bulleted list of links? Like the example below.

Let's say "Services" is the parent page and its children pages are "Grass Cutting", "Water Gardens", and "Landscaping".

count($children) would return 3 for the "Services" page since it has 3 children. Now it should echo them as so:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Grass Cutting</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Water Gardens</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Landscaping</a></li>
</ul>
```

a href= should be the link to the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you just need to run a `foreach` loop over your `$children` but WordPress has a build in function for this already called `wp list pages`.

For example:

```
$children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=1');

if ($children)
echo '<ul>' . $children . '</ul>';
```

There is a full reference and examples here:   http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages

Comment: I did consult the reference you linked before posting and understand the loop part but how do I echo the links in the loop?

Comment: The function will automatically create links and wrap the link in an `<li>`, you can change the output, have a look at the `$args` parameters.

Comment: Sorry my example had `echo=0`, to have it return link you need to `echo=1`, I changed the above example.